# Full database export failing in Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, expdp

Command executed:

```
expdp SHELAZ/SHELAZ full=Y directory=dpump_dir dumpfile=SHELAZ20221215.dmp logfile=logfile.log
```

Facing below error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31633: unable to create master table "SHELAZ.SYS_EXPORT_FULL_90"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT", line 1048
ORA-01658: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace SHELAZDISTDATA
```

Ran: `select * from dba_datapump_jobs`

Results: 85 rows with State = NOT RUNNING

Comment: Well, you're out of space in that tablespace (or have exceeded your quota, have no quota at all on; the message might vary depending on which). Check the tablespace size and free space and whether it can grow, and your quota.

Comment: you are right had totally missed this one let me look into extending it.